# Returning data from a specific column AND row using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm changing my ways and converting my site from using mysql_query to PDO and I'm stumped.

Before I would query my database and retrieve a specific column from specific rows like this:

```
$getPhotos_query = "select * from resultsPhotos where fk_surveyID = 1 and fk_itemID = 123 order by resultPhotoID";
$getPhotos_result = mssql_query($getPhotos_query);  

$thisPhoto1 = mssql_result($getPhotos_result, 0, 'resultPhotoFile');
$thisPhoto2 = mssql_result($getPhotos_result, 1, 'resultPhotoFile');
$thisPhoto3 = mssql_result($getPhotos_result, 2, 'resultPhotoFile');
```

Now I see the error in my ways and converting to PDO like this

```
$getPhotos_query = $conn->prepare('select * from resultsPhotos where fk_surveyID = :surveyID and fk_itemID = :itemID order by resultPhotoID');
$getPhotos_query->execute(array('surveyID' => 1,'itemID' => 123));
$getPhotos_result = $getPhotos_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

But now I can't figure out how to retrieve the resultPhotoFile column from each of the three returned rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$getPhotos_result[0]->resultPhotoFile`

Answer (score 1):

```
$thisPhoto1 = $getPhotos_result[0]->resultPhotoFile;
$thisPhoto2 = $getPhotos_result[1]->resultPhotoFile;
$thisPhoto3 = $getPhotos_result[2]->resultPhotoFile;
```

But if you prefer working with arrays instead of objects, you could use

```
$getPhotos_query->fetchAll();
```

instead which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH

You can check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to find the fetch_style that suits you best.